Custom Ajax callback is not working within layout builder
I am using custom ajax callback inside an block form using form_alter but ajax functionality is not working within layout builder where as its working as expected while adding from structure -> block layout -> add custom block
I have used block form alter module (https://www.drupal.org/project/block_form_alter).
I tried with fresh drupal 10.2.5 as well.
Expected result:
On select of field type, title and description field value should be changed
Below are the code I used to alter form and using ajax
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (preg_match('/block_content_(.*)_form/', $form_id, $matches)
    || $form_id == 'layout_builder_add_block'
    || $form_id == 'layout_builder_update_block'
    || $form_id == 'block_form') {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="card-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
}


function custom_module_block_type_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, string $block_type) {
  if ($block_type == 'basic') {
    $form['field_type']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'fetchArticleDetails',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'card-form-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ];

    $type = $form_state->getValue('field_type');
    if (!empty($type[0]['value'])) {
      $form['field_title']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'title ' . $type[0]['value'];
      $form['field_description']['widget'][0]['#value'] = 'desc ' . $type[0]['value'];
    }
  }
}


function fetchArticleDetails(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form;
}

May be I am missing something, please suggest.
